# Apache ever match a virtual host with a different ServerName

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.4

i have an issue.
I have a VirtualHost for domain1.com on IP 1.2.3.4, but Apache reply to the request to the IP 1.2.3.4 ignoring the ServerName.

So, if i point domain2.com to 1.2.3.4 i see the content of /var/www/html/domain1.com and not the content of /var/www/html/default

What is wrong?

```
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
SSLEngine off
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain1.com
ServerName www.domain1.com:80
<Directory "/var/www/html/domain1.com">
allow from all
</Directory>
  LogLevel notice
UseCanonicalName on
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/default
<Directory /var/www/html/default>
allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use of `_default_` here will match IPs that have not been defined for another `VirtualHost`. This means that a request to `1.2.3.4:80` according to your config will use the first defined `VirtualHost` for `www.domain1.com`. Priority of `VirtualHost` are defined by their order in the config file.

To achieve the configuration you desire, move your default `VirtualHost` above the `www.domain1.com` one, and change its IP from `_default_` to `1.2.3.4`.

Further information on the specifics of this are listed in the Apache manual which you can find at this [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html).